# importing base64 encoded fonts in PIL

Tags: python, fonts, base64, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load a true type font in Pil from a base64 encoded string, 
with this code:

```
import base64
from PIL import ImageFont
from io import BytesIO

TTF = "T1RUTwAJAIAAAwAQQ0ZGIGkSYyMAAACcAA"  # ...this is obviously only part of the string representing a base64 encoded ttf file

fontub = ImageFont.ImageFont()
fontub._load_pilfont_data(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(TTF)),None)
```

but i am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Not a PILfont file

i want to include all the font/images in my project in a resource.py file as base64 encoded string resources. I already did it with all the icons and images, but i cant find a way to this with fonts Is there any way to do it?

PS: i am using python 3.4.4/windows 10 and Pillow 3.4.2 and i am using notepad++ to encode the ttf file.

Comment: The `_load_pilfont_data` function loads a pilfont data (and **not** a TTF font).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment, the `_load_pilfont_data` function loads a PILFont data (and not a data of TTF font file), so if you try to use that function to load a TTF font - you will get a SyntaxError (because it's not a PILfont file).

What you can do - is use the `truetype` function of the `ImageFont` module:

```
import base64
from PIL import ImageFont
from io import BytesIO

TTF = "T1RUTwAJAIAAAwAQQ0ZGIGkSYyMAAACcAA" 
fontub = ImageFont.truetype(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(TTF)))
```

In the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype) is said you should provide the path to the file, but it seems like a `BytesIO` also works.